# Why does my grunt-contrib-requirejs does not optimize anything?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I am trying to get up and running with the [grunt-contrib-requirejs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) task.
Being new to RequireJS in general and having never used the optimizer/r.js, I am really confused how to get this to work.

As a start, I have set up a simple directory structure like this:

```
root
├── js
│   ├── helper
│   │   ├── a.js
│   │   ├── b.js
│   │   └── d-dep.js
│   └── main.js
├── node_modules
│   └── [dependencies from package.json]
├── Gruntfile.js
└── package.json
```

I've tested it in the browser and all dependencies are loaded correctly there.

My Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.config.init({
    requirejs: {
      options: {
        baseUrl: 'js/',
        mainConfigFile: 'js/main.js',
        dir: 'target/',
        keepBuildDir: true
      }
    }
  });

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
}
```

main.js:

```
require(["helper/a", "helper/b"], function(util) {
  console.log('main.js loaded');
});
```

a.js

```
console.log('a.js loaded');
```

b.js

```
define(['js/helper/b-dep.js'], function(bdep) {
  console.log('b.js loaded');
});
```

b-dep.js

```
console.log('b.js dependency loaded');
```

When running `grunt requirejs`, I get a `Done, without errors.` message, but can't see any optimized file – I am guessing the error is in the Gruntfile, probably with the path.

Do you see anything that strikes you? Why is nothing optimized, although it says `Done, without errors.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be telling it to optimize *something*. You should have a `name` option set to tell it what the main module is. Also you are missing one level of configuration in the configuration you pass to grunt. The `options` object must be inside of a more specific target, like `compile`:

```
requirejs: {
  compile: { // <<== nest the options in this.
    options: {
      baseUrl: 'js/',
      mainConfigFile: 'js/main.js',
      name : 'main', // <<=== add this
      dir: 'target/',
      keepBuildDir: true
    }
  }
}
```

Setting the `mainConfigFile` is not enough because this only tells the optimizer where it should get the *runtime configuration* from. It does not tell the optimizer that the file is a module. Note that the lack of `.js` extension in `name` is not an error. You should avoid using extension in module names, unless there is a specific reason that calls for an extension. And `name` is relative to `baseUrl` so this is why it is `'main'` not `'js/main'`.

Comment: Thanks! having looked up the possible options for `r.js` again, I also noticed I was missing `out`, which specifies the name of the output file. Unfortunately, it's still not working – do I need to add something to my `main.js`, some more config?

Comment: My initial answer was produce by eyeballing your code. I've reproduced your config here and noticed another issue. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Wow, finally it's working! Thank you! I've still gone an error in my module tree, but thats fixable for me – after banging my head against the wall for hours ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my config, this is what I use to create a file called `all.js`

```
     requirejs : {
        dist : {
          options : {
            waitSeconds : 0,
            baseUrl : "./app/",
            name : 'assets/js/main',
            mainConfigFile: 'app/assets/js/main.js',
            out : "dist/assets/js/all.js",
            optimize : "uglify2",
            inlineText : true,
            findNestedDependencies : true,
            paths : {
                requireLib : "assets/bower_components/requirejs/require",
            },
            include : [
                "requireLib"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you maybe post the corresponding file/folder structure?